# AWS IOT - how to simulate a thing to publish an MQTT message to a topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

Apologies if this is a noob.  I am trying to learn the ropes of AWS IOT.

I understand that I can use a client like MQTT.fx to publish messages to a topic in a message broker

I also see that AWS IOT resources console, I can create things, attach certificates, policies, and create rules.

If I create a thing say 'car' using the IOT resources console, is there some way that the console gives where i can have the car publish MQTT messages to a topic?  Or is the only way wiring up the simulate car to an actual device using the SDK.

Like I mentioned, I am aware of publishing through an MQTT client.  I just want to understand how to make a 'thing' I created in the resources console, to publish the MQTT messages to a message broker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for information how to obtain endpoint that will handle subscribe and publish messages. This is described in [Verify MQTT Subscribe and Publish](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/verify-pub-sub.html) section of Developers Guide. Using AWS CLI:

```
aws iot describe-endpoint
```

It will return something like that:

```
{
    "endpointAddress": "ABCDEF12345678.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Your thing should use one of existing [AWS IoT SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/iot/sdk/) to subscribe to MQTT topic and start publishing some data ie. speed, fuel consumption, etc.

In general you can simulate your thing (ie. car) by subscribing to some topic:

```
mosquitto_sub --cafile "path-to-cert\rootCA.pem" --cert "path-to-cert\cert.pem" \
--key "path-to-cert\privateKey.pem" \
-h "ABCDEF12345678.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t "topic/test" \
-i "car1"
```

Then in other terminal you can publish:

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile rootCA.pem --cert certs\cert.pem --key privateKey.pem \
-h "ABCDEF12345678.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -p 8883 -q 1 -d -t topic/test 
-i car2 -m "Hello, World"
```

Comment: I'm getting a Error: Loading Tls options. when using the mosquitto_pub, the mosquitto_sub command works just fine. I'm in mac system though. Anything I may be missing?